# Python 3, float numbers from tk radio button into formula for math

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a formula that i need to alter a specific figure based on which of a radio button is selected at the time of the execution of the formula.

buttons are as follows currently:-

```
radioframe = Frame(window)
glthick = DoubleVar()
radio_1 = Radiobutton(radioframe,text='12mm',\
variable = glthick,value=86.67)
radio_2 = Radiobutton(radioframe,text='15mm',\
variable = glthick,value=191.19)
radio_1.select()
```

My understanding is that whichever button is selected will apply the responding value to the variable "glthick"?

I then attempt to convert this figure into a floating point number for use in the following equation, please dont try to read the equation, the math is sound.

```
def formulaexecute():
    val1 = (entry1.get())
    val2 = (entry2.get())
    glthickval = float(glthick)
    try:
       floatval1 = float(val1)
       floatval2 = float(val2)
    except ValueError:
        message = "The numbers you have entered are not valid numbers"
        print("Error!", message)
        box.showerror("Invalid Input", message)
    floatval1 = float(val1)
    floatval2 = float(val2)
    bevel = (((floatval1/100)*2)+((floatval2/100)*2))*3.5
    formula12 = (((((((floatval1/100)*(floatval2)/100))*glthickval)+bevel+44)*2.4)*1.1)
    glprice12 = formula12 + bevel
    showprice12 = str(glprice12)[:4]
    box.showinfo('Final Calculation',('Your table is:+entry1.get()+'x'+en
```

You see after formula12 = the attempted use of the float value from the radio button in glthickval, the float converted version of the radio button value.

The error returned is "float() argument must be a string or number", i know alot of people get these because of incorrectly having values that cant be floated inputted but i know in this case that i do not. so im at a loss.

The error specifically reports glthickval = float(glthick) as the line causing issues, but it works fine for every other version of it.

Maybe its blindingly simple, but assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Solution:-

```
glthickval = (glthick.get())
glthickvalfloat = float(glthickval)
```

Kind Regards, Lewis

Comment: And the lord shall help those who help themselves.

Utter bollocks of course, but i found the issue, the issue was that the radio button assigns the variable a figure based on its selection but then requires a call function to pull that figure out, then attribute it as a float figure for use in the following formula.

Took me a while but i got it, hopefully anyone else trying to figure this out will read this. i edited the original post to show the corrected code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glthick` is an object rather than a number, so you must use `.get()` to get the value:

```
glthickval = glthick.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the issue was that the radio button assigns the variable a figure based on its selection but then requires a call function to pull that figure out, then attribute it as a float figure for use in the following formula. Took me a while but i got it, hopefully anyone else trying to figure this out will read this. i edited the original post to show the corrected code block.